# If statement considers FALSE promise as TRUE

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm making authentication in my app.
And have such code

```
  const ttt = currentUser.changedPasswordAfter(decoded.iat);
  console.log(ttt);
  if (ttt) {
    console.log('if thinks ttt is true');
```

changedPasswordAfter retuns promise (true or false)
So I run request and get this into console.

```
Promise { false }
if thinks ttt is true
```

As you see ttt is FALSE but IF statement decided that it is TRUE .
How can I fix that ?

Comment: It's not `true` it's [_truthy_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Comment: @evolutionxbox ???

Comment: Please have a look at the link. A promise is _truthy_. What is `currentUser.changedPasswordAfter`?

Comment: @David read the link that @evolutionxbox sent. In short, truthy means it evaluates to true, even if it's not the literal `true`

Comment: A promise is an object, an object is converted to true. If you want your value you need to `await` or call `then`. `ttt.then(res => /* here res is true or false*/)`

Comment: @evolutionxbox
 Promise { false }

Comment: a `Promise` is an object that contains data, which is one of the possible ways for something to be truthy/evaluate to true in if/else expressions or similar things

Comment: @David the `if` is only concerned about the `Promise` *itself*, not the data that's resolved. if you said `if (await ttt) { ... }` inside of an `async` function, it would work, or if you `await`ed in the variable defintion

Comment: Thanks guys I understood your point.! :)

Comment: just to add something to the boilerplate, please never name a variable `ttt`. Never.

Comment: @briosheje that was just for testing purposes, while I was investigating the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ttt (which is a very bad name for a variable) is a Promise not a boolean so the if statement return True because the variable ttt has reference (is not undefined or null).
try to add `await` keyword. it will work but you have to make the function Async

```
const ttt = await currentUser.changedPasswordAfter(decoded.iat);
  console.log(ttt);
  if (ttt) {
    console.log('if thinks ttt is true');
```

Answer (score 2):

Promise is an object - so, it is "truthy". Only the resolved value of the promise can be true or false. To give the promise a chance to resolve, either the `await` or the `Promise.then` method should be used.

```
const ttt = currentUser.changedPasswordAfter(decoded.iat);
ttt.then((result) => {
   if (result)
     console.log('Promise returned true')
   else
     console.log('Promise returned false')
})
```

Comment: or use this promise.then based approach.

Comment: Charlie Thanks for solution but Rafaa was first one. Both are correct will accept AWAIT one. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem. My aim was to offer help. Please accept Ralaa's answer.

Comment: Once more thank you :) both solutions are great :)